# Session not cleared when logging out of Liferay in third party application

Tags: session, jsf, liferay, cas, invalidation

An application has been integrated into liferay using iFrame. Application is developed in JSF with bean being in session scoped. For authentication CAS has been used with liferay. The application uses login username of liferay. When liferay is loggout out, the session of application is not cleared so because of which logging with another account shows old data. How can I clear the session of application when logging out of liferay?

Looking for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [`com.liferay.portal.action.LogoutAction.execute()`](http://docs.liferay.com/portal/5.2/javadocs/portal-impl/com/liferay/portal/action/LogoutAction.java.html.) method. Here at *line#100*.

You have to call your jsf application code at this moment to invalidate the session that you have in that particular application.

Now, in order to change the `LogoutAction`, you can use the EXT environment or you can write the code into `LogoutPostAction` by modifying the same using hook.

Comment: I am writing Hook with LogoutPreAction and it works well in my computer. But while deploying into the server, old setting of portal properties is taken; it hasn't been overridden. What could be the problem?

Comment: Could you please be specific on the old settings? which properties are taken with old values?

Comment: By old setting I mean default setting 

logout.events.pre=com.liferay.portal.events.LogoutPreAction

Comment: Hi, in your hook, as the properties file also and override property like logout.events.pre=com.liferay.portal.events.LogoutPreAction,<your customLogoutPreAction package path with class name>

Comment: Yes, I did and it works fine in my machine but while deploying in Server it doesn't work; portal.properties is not overridden.

Comment: In that case, you must have some property file at the server root level, try to edit that property file and provide new value for logout.events.pre

Comment: Trying to find the original portal.properties file but not being able to. Changes made inside generated/jsp/.....doesn't make any difference (instead those files are changed in every server restart). What can I do ?

Comment: Hi, please create a file portal-ext.properties at \webapps\ROOT\WEB-INF\classes, and put logout.events.pre with both the classes. Restart the server and try to deploy the hook

Comment: Hi Felix, following above suggestion, I can see logout.events.pre being overridden by my Action. But the my custom hook action is not been invoked while I logout of liferay. What could be the problem ?